# .htaccess and SEO URLs - why is this an infinite loop?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have a dirty URL like this: http://www.netairspace.com/photos/photo.php?photo=3392.
I want to do something like http://www.netairspace.com/photos/OH-LTU/Finnair_Airbus_330-202X/OUL_EFOU_Oulu/photo_3392/ (and later support short URLs like http://www.netairspace.com/pic/3392/ but I'll leave that out).

So I have a script photo_seo_url.php, which takes the photo ID, builds the SEO URL, and does a redirect (302 for testing, 301 when I'm happy with it). I then planned to add .htaccess mod_rewrite rules so that on calling the old URL:

- the old URL would be rewritten internally to photo_seo_url.php
- photo_seo_url.php would 301/302 redirect to the SEO URL
- the SEO URL would be rewritten internally to the original photo.php

That way I would, in theory, get the benefits of the SEO URL while being able to retire the old ones at my leisure.

These are the rules I used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^photos/.*/photo_([0-9]+)/?$ photos/photo.php?photo=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} photo=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^photos/photo\.php$ photos/photo_seo_url.php?photo=%1 [NC,L]
```

But that goes into an infinite redirect loop. Why, if these two are doing internal rewrites rather than external redirects - or is that what I'm missing?

I've solved the problem adding a new file showphoto.php, which does nothing but include the original photo.php, and changing line 2:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^photos/.*/photo_([0-9]+)/?$ photos/showphoto.php?photo=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} photo=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^photos/photo\.php$ photos/photo_seo_url.php?photo=%1 [NC,L]
```

But I'd still like to understand why the original version goes into an infinite loop. I've missed or misunderstood something. Is my approach sound?

Comment: The first set of rules look fine to me - if you can, try to add some rewrite logging to see what's happening. I couldn't spot a case where there would be a loop.

Comment: I added a RewriteLog to httpd.conf with a debug level 4, as per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog, and restarted. On making the request, a blank log file is created.

Comment: Accidentally submitted that comment half way through. If I request the SEO URL (which successfully appears), the loop happens after that.

Comment: Yes but what does the log say? If you set it at level 3, you should be able to spot what's being rewritten, what's being matched and why.

Comment: That's the thing - it's blank, 0kb. Nothing in it!

Comment: Make sure it's writable by the web server, and make sure to restart the server after adding those lines to the VirtualHost config.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12177/discussion-between-ed-daniel-and-ansari)

Comment: Apache created that log file, so should have been able to write in it, no?

Comment: I'm getting different behaviour every time I go back and forth between logging and not logging, a sure sign I'm getting too tired to gain anything useful from the exercise. You wrote: "The first set of rules look fine to me - if you can, try to add some rewrite logging to see what's happening. I couldn't spot a case where there would be a loop." Put that as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh no don't do that if it doesn't solve your problem - let me know if you still want to keep at it.

Comment: Not tonight, it's way after bedtime here in Finland...

Comment: I'll take another look tomorrow when I'm fresh, maybe take it up then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, why does this loop occur?  This is what happens with an SEO URI, with a `GET /photos/OH-LTU/Finnair_Airbus_330-202X/OUL_EFOU_Oulu/photo_3392/`, say.

- Rule 1 fires converting this to a `GET /photos/photo.php?photo=3392` which triggers an internal redirect which then restarts the scan of the `.htaccess`file.
- Rule 2 then fires converting this to a `GET photos/photo_seo_url.php?photo=339` which triggers an internal redirect which again restarts the scan of the `.htaccess`file.
- No further matches occur and hence this is passed to the script `photos/photo_seo_url.php` which then does a 302 to `/photos/OH-LTU/Finnair_Airbus_330-202X/OUL_EFOU_Oulu/photo_3392/` and the browser detects a redirection loop.

What you need happen is for rule 1 firing to prevent rule 2 firing even after an internal redirect.  One way to do this is to set an environment variable, say END (which gets converted to REDIRECT_END on the next pass) and to skip the rules if this is set:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /

RewriteRule   ^photos/.*/photo_([0-9]+)/?$ photos/photo.php?photo=$1 [NC,E=END:1,L]

RewriteCond   %{ENV:REDIRECT_END}:%{QUERY_STRING}   ^:photo=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule   ^photos/photo\.php$          photos/photo_seo_url.php?photo=%1 [NC,L]
```

An alternative approach is to add a dummy `noredir` parameter to the rewritten URI and add a:

```
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   !\bnoredir
```

to the original second rule.  However, `photo.php` would need to ignore this.  Hope this helps :-)

Comment: "which triggers an internal redirect which then restarts the scan of the .htaccess file." THAT'S what I was missing. Thank you. In production I'll probably stick with my existing solution or rename photo.php because I understand that better, but I'll definitely be trying it your way on my dev system so I can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^photos/.*/photo_([0-9]+)/?$ photos/photo.php?photo=$1&rewritten [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rewritten
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} photo=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^photos/photo\.php$ photos/photo_seo_url.php?photo=%1 [NC,L]
```